# Want to add character instead of date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have this small query in Snowflake

```
WITH Date_Generator AS ( 
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), '2021-01-01')        AS date_id 
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>3000))
),

Final AS ( 
  SELECT  
    DATE(date_id)                                                   AS date_id,
    CASE  
        WHEN DATE(date_id) = current_date() THEN 'Today' 
        ELSE DATE(date_id)
    END                                                             AS date_filter, 
    DAYNAME(date_id)                                                AS day_name, 
    DAY(date_id)                                                    AS day_number_month
  FROM Date_Generator
  WHERE  date_id <= DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())
)

SELECT 
  *
FROM Final
```

here we are trying to say that if date_id is current date then give us as 'Today' but when we trying to use the following query it gives us error `Date 'Today' is not recognized`, could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Date 'Today' is not recognized

```
CASE  
    WHEN DATE(date_id) = current_date() THEN 'Today'    -- varchar
    ELSE DATE(date_id)  -- date
END
```

If 'Today' should be accepted the it is no longer date:

```
CASE  
    WHEN DATE(date_id) = current_date() THEN 'Today'  
    ELSE TO_VARCHAR(DATE(date_id), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
END
```

---

Second [SEQ](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1):

> This function uses sequences to produce a unique set of increasing integers, but does not necessarily produce a gap-free sequence. When operating on a large quantity of data, gaps can appear in a sequence. **If a fully ordered, gap-free sequence is required, consider using the ROW_NUMBER window function**

```
SELECT 
   DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), '2021-01-01')        AS date_id 
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>3000))

=>
SELECT 
   DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SEQ4()), '2021-01-01')        AS date_id 
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>3000))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the date to string if you want to mix the date and string in case statement result. Please try this.

```
WITH Date_Generator AS ( 
  SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, SEQ4(), '2021-01-01')        AS date_id 
  FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>3000))
),

Final AS ( 
  SELECT  
    DATE(date_id)                                                   
AS date_id,
    CASE  
        WHEN DATE(date_id) = current_date() THEN 'Today' 
        ELSE DATE(date_id)::STRING
    END                                                             
AS date_filter, 
    DAYNAME(date_id)                                                
AS day_name, 
    DAY(date_id)                                                    
AS day_number_month
  FROM Date_Generator
  WHERE  date_id <= DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())
)

SELECT 
  *
FROM Final
```

Comment: With this query works, but we are not able to get 'Today' instead of todays date(current date)

Comment: @Jensen please try now. I have updated the query as per your expected output.